# multiple responses to client of WCF service

Tags: c#

I need your guidance.The scenario is, client c1 send request to WCF service.Then WCF service start one EXE EXE1 at server side.EXE1 writes some data in PIPE,then WCF Service will read that data and send response to client c1.
          But if EXE1 again writes some data in Pipe then WCF service read that data and again send it to client C1 and so on....in this case client not sending new request but still getting multiple responses from WCF service.
          client may be in c# or in c language,so it should not be dependent on client

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a [DUPLEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) service. The MSDN article has a nice example of a Calculator Duplex service

Comment: client may be in c# or in c language,so it should not be dependent on client

Comment: @sunilpol, you can do your task by duplex service but if you have a c++ code, you could move it in VC and use `com` to communicate with c# services.